# Spring Boot IT test after Deploy

Tags: java, spring-boot, automated-tests, integration-testing

I have Spring Boot Integration tests (IT) that connect to a real DB or to a real 3rd parties. I use them during development but I find them quite usefull to check the real behaviour of the application therefore I would like to run them during CI process. The goal is to run them on the environment on which the application is deployed and **not on CI machine** where Jenkins is running. Is there a way how to achieve this? I know I can use for example SOAP UI maven plugin and execute tests against REST endpoints, but I would prefer to use Spring Boot IT tests already written.

Many thanks

Answer (score -1):

Running tests against your production database is a really bad idea. Please please please reconsider.  It is better to have your test database updated to be more like production than to run your tests on production data.

That being said, you can point your database configuration to your production machine via the application.properties file (mongo example):

```
spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://user:pass@production.myhost.com:27017/mydb
```

I'm guessing that it defaults to localhost:27017. In your test/resources folder you can setup a differing application.properties.  Check out the [spring-boot externalized properties details](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html).

Comment: Hi.I never said it would run against production database. The question is more about how to use existing tests with @SpringBootTest to be run on target environment (dev, test) than trying to find another solution.

Comment: On my tests, the active profile is set to 'test'.  So I create a custom configuration in src/test/resources/application-test.properties - this allows for a differing configuration from what is in src/main/resources/application.properties. The link to externalized properties has details on how it adds active profile to the properties file names, and the order of precedence.